# Cannot get post_content in customize page?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I've created a customize page show all posts with template:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: All posts
*/

get_header();
?>
</header>
<div role="main" id="content" class="content-warp">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="primary" class="content-area col-md-8 post-list">
            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="post">
                        <div class="entry">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                            <?php
                            $current_date = "";
                            $count_posts = wp_count_posts();
                            $nextpost = 0;
                            $published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
                            $myposts = get_posts(array('posts_per_page' => $published_posts));

                            foreach ($myposts as $post) :
                                get_template_part('content', 'content-single');
                                ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php get_sidebar('page'); ?>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But it not show post_content of Posts (all remain data are normal).

By the way, with default UI Categories (content.php), i just call below code and everything Ok: the same UI with new template but have post_content).

`<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>`

I don't know why post_content is null in new my template. I'm using Llorix One LiteVersion: 0.1.7

Any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I try read [document](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) again and realize the_content not set data yet.
So, just add setup post data, look like:

```
...
foreach($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post );
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Also You can use new WP Query

```
$myposts = new WP_QUery(array(
    'posts_per_page' => $published_posts
));

if ($myposts->have_posts()): ?>
    <?php while ($myposts->have_posts()) {
            $myposts->the_post();

            get_template_part('content', 'content-single');
    } ?>
<?php endif ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```